# Android clickable layouts above empty views

Tags: android-layout, layout, xamarin, android-relativelayout

My project also uses Xamarin with MvvmCross, but I don't think this will effect the answer since the problem is all view-layout/axml related.

I have a GridView that summarizes a list of contacts. When clicking on this grid view, I would like the user to be taken to another screen to add more contacts to this list (so there is more space).
Subscribing to the GridView's OnClick event gives me an exception, saying I should be subscribing to the item click event, so I have done this using a clickable relative layout that surrounds the GridView (and its accompanying empty image view) as such:

```xml
...
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/addContactsRelativeLayout"
            android:clickable="true">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/empty"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_add" />
            <Mvx.MvxGridView
                android:id="@+id/addContactsGridView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Contacts"
                local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/contact_summary_item"
                android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:columnWidth="55dip"
                android:gravity="center" />
        </RelativeLayout>
...
```

This works fine when the GridView is empty, and the empty ImageView is shown. However, when there are items in the GridView, the RelativeLayout no longer seems to exist and clicks over the GridView can be seen to highlight items on the GridView. This means the user is not taken to the screen to edit their contact list.

I have tried several different configurations and attributes from similar questions on SO, but I think the addition of an empty view is causing problems. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a lot more playing around I found a solution.

Essentially it's adding another relative layout, higher in the z-index and therefore above the 'real' contents, within the surrounding relative layout.

```
...
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/empty"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_add" />
            <Mvx.MvxGridView
                android:id="@+id/addContactsGridView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Contacts"
                local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/contact_summary_item"
                android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:columnWidth="55dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:focusable="false"/>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:id="@+id/addContactsRelativeLayout"/>
...
```

Then just move all your click listeners to listen to the relative layout at the bottom.